# Cleanest way to reset a class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that looks like the following

```
class A:
    communicate = set()
    def __init__(self):
         pass
    ...
    def _some_func(self):
       ...some logic...
       self.communicate.add(some_var)
```

The communicate variable is shared among the instances of the class. I use it to provide a convenient way for the instances of this class to communicate with one another (they have some mild orchestration needed and I don't want to force the calling object to serve as an intermediary of this communication). However, I realized this causes problems when I run my tests. If I try to test multiple aspects of my code, since the python interpreter is the same throughout all the tests, I won't get a "fresh" A class for the tests, and as such the `communicate` set will be the aggregate of all objects I add to that set (in normal usage this is exactly what I want, but for testing I don't want interactions between my tests). Furthermore, down the line this will also cause problems in my code execution if I want to loop over my whole process multiple times (because I won't have a way of resetting this class variable).

I know I can fix this issue where it occurs by having the creator of the A objects do something like

```
A.communicate = set()
```

before it creates and uses any instances of A. However, I don't really love this because it forces my caller to know some details about the communication pathways of the A objects, and I don't want that coupling. Is there a better way for me to to reset the `communicate` A class variable? Perhaps some method I could call on the class instead of an instance itself like (`A.new_batch()`) that would perform this resetting? Or is there a better way I'm not familiar with?

Edit:
I added a class method like

```
class A:
    communicate = set()
    def __init__(self):
         pass
    ...
    @classmethod
    def new_batch(cls):
       cls.communicate = set()
    def _some_func(self):
       ...some logic...
       self.communicate.add(some_var)
```

and this works with the caller running `A.new_batch()`. Is this the way it should be constructed and called, or is there a better practice here?

Comment: when are you clearing the set is there any condition?

Comment: The higher level objects that call class A operate on documents (the instances of A represent parts of a document). Thus the reset would occur once for each new document.

Comment: check contextmanager can be suitable for your usecase